# Fetch Linq to Entity result directly into Datatable

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, datatable

I am trying to make dynamic menu using **Linq and entity**. I wants to add query result directly into datatable. select query (as shown below)  throws an exception.
Exception:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Data.DataRow
>   LoadDataRow(System.Object[], Boolean)' method, and this method cannot
>   be translated into a store expression

Is there alternative? Here below is my code.

```
DataTable dtMenu = new DataTable();
dtMenu.Columns.Add("MenuName", typeof(string));
dtMenu.Columns.Add("SubMenuName", typeof(string));
dtMenu.Columns.Add("FileName", typeof(string));

var menuItems = (from vUser in dbMenu.VirtualUserMenuMaps
join menu in dbMenu.MenuMasters on vUser.MenuId equals menu.MenuId
join subMenu in dbMenu.SubMenuMasters on vUser.SubMenuId equals subMenu.SubMenuId
where vUser.VirtualId == virtualId
orderby menu.MenuId, subMenu.DisplayOrder
select dtMenu.LoadDataRow(
new object[] { menu.MenuName, subMenu.SubMenuName, subMenu.FileName }, false));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't call a method that can't be translated into `SQL query`, you should do in 2 steps like this:

```
var menuItems =  from vUser in dbMenu.VirtualUserMenuMaps
                 join menu in dbMenu.MenuMasters on vUser.MenuId equals menu.MenuId
                 join subMenu in dbMenu.SubMenuMasters on vUser.SubMenuId equals subMenu.SubMenuId
                 where vUser.VirtualId == virtualId
                 orderby menu.MenuId, subMenu.DisplayOrder
                 select new { menu.MenuName, subMenu.SubMenuName, subMenu.FileName };
foreach(var row in menuItems)
    dtMenu.LoadDataRow(new object[]{row.MenuName, row.SubMenuName, row.FileName}, false);
```